# How to create a docker proxy repo with gcr.io?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

My settings: [image]

logs:

> 2017-07-18 01:49:01,592+0000 WARN  [qtp330844155-323] admin
> org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: GET
> /v2/gcr.io/google-containers/addon-resizer/manifests/2.0: 403 -
> org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception: Permission
> denied for "2.0" from request
> "/v2/gcr.io/google-containers/addon-resizer/manifests/2.0".

Comment: Interesting. Can you file an issue at: https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/NEXUS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

the pull address have to without origin registry hosts

e.g:

origin:
docker pull gcr.io/google-containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.6.3

with proxy:
docker pull 127.0.0.1:18883/google-containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.6.3

Comment: Isn't that a problem as then all the gcr.io images are tagged 127.0.0.1:18883 ?